# Ivy error after cloning code

Tags: eclipse, ivy, ivyde

I recieve the following error when i am cloning an exiting repo:

```
Unrecognized variables in the Ivy settings file ${workspace_loc:PersonProject/ivysettings.xml}  ivy.xml /StudentProject
```

I believe i need to change the `workspace_loc` to the correct value - `StudentProject`

However i cannot find where to change this. I have checked under Windows->Preferences->Ivy->Settings

Also the ivysettings.xml file

How can i fix this please?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVYDE-302